# if condition works only once when selecting more than limit files

Tags: javascript, html

I have to refresh the page if i want this alert message again.

```js
document.getElementById("images").addEventListener("change", function() {
  var length = this.files.length;
  if (length > 2) {
    alert("you can not select more than 2 files")
  }
});
```

```html
<input class="control4" name="images[]" id="images" multiple="multiple" name="images" type="file" accept="image/jpg, image/jpeg,image/png" />
```

Comment: I chose three files, got the alert.  Chose one, no alert.  Chose three again, got alert again.  I cannot replicate your issue.

Comment: I chose three files, got the alert.  I chose three different files than the first time, I got the alert.

Comment: Did the value actually change?

Comment: can any body help me on this plzzz https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52089017/how-to-save-the-image-in-multiple-file-handling-after-removing-one-of-them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works for me, are you choosing the same file on the second time? Change event only fires when the value changes, it can be fixed by setting value of input to empty string.

```js
document.getElementById("images").addEventListener("change", function() {
  var length = this.files.length;
  if (length > 2) {
    this.value = "";
    alert("you can not select more than 2 files");
  }
});
```

```html
<input class="control4" name="images[]" id="images" multiple="multiple" name="images" type="file" accept="image/jpg, image/jpeg,image/png" />
```